# What's a B*Tree?

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

What's a [B*Tree](http://stderr.org/doc/ntfsdoc/concepts/tree/index.html)? Did they just mean binary search tree?

Comment: Nope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Comment: Oooh I did not know that. But so is the asterisk just the same as a dash? I thought it might have a special meaning.

Comment: It does; (I believe) the * means that the nodes are at least 2/3 full.

Comment: @dlev: Haha I should've read more of that before asking, it's in the article. :-) Feel free to post it as the answer, that's really helpful! (Edit: or... maybe not, someone already beat you to the punch apparently, haha.)

Comment: @dlev you are correct. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Variants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A node in a B*Tree can have many keys (which point to many children). They operate by comparing keys in order to select a child node, much like a binary tree. But, the intent is that each node is stored on disk, and can be read into memory at once. Thus, the number of disk accesses required would match the depth of the tree.

Answer (score 5):

[Nope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). Note that the * indicates the nodes are at least 2/3 full.